# Why does the CSS of Stack Overflow need a v parameter?

Tags: support

I am working at a customer with rather restrictive Internet access. I didn't have any problems with Stack Exchange websites so far (except [Anime & Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour)). But now it seems the CSS is blocked due to the "v" URL parameter making it look like dynamic content and thus harmful:

```
http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/all.css?v=f46e20d518dc
```

If I access the CSS without the parameter the firewall lets the CSS through, so I'm assuming this was added recently (I never checked it before).

So can it be removed again or any suggestions on how I can access the page with CSS nonetheless?

Comment: It's probably to avoid caching issues. Changing the parameter forces the clients to download the CSS again.

Comment: recent like since 2009? - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25929/errors-in-sstatic-net-css-file

Comment: Any chance of getting the customer to whitelist the site? Are you able to install an addon to your browser to use custom stylesheets?

Comment: Ah, the irony of blocking the static content of a dynamic website because dynamic somehow equals harmful. Whoever made this rule clearly lacks basic understanding of how the web works.

Comment: Please, by all means, tell the people responsible for this to visit this question so that we may mock them mercilessly.

Comment: today it works again, strange policy they have in place there...

Comment: and today it blocks the JS for the Inbox and achievements click events, e.g. the ajax call triggered by it...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

We deploy several times a day - some of these updates could be to CSS.

Our CSS is cached - on multiple levels (CDN, proxies, your browser).

In order to ensure that you get the newest CSS (and JavaScript), we need to "cache bust" - that is, ensure that the browser (and all caching proxies and the CDN) will get a fresh copy of the file. This is done by appending a parameter to the URL (the v - for version) - when a file changes, the value changes.

This is very common practice - and not something we will change. This is overly restrictive of your client - sorry if it is causing problems.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. Strange is only that it used to work before and now it doesn't. But there would be a better way to do it, add the timestamp or key before the extension e.g. all.f46e20d518dc.css So it can still be cached if the same version is requested

Comment: I would call it best practice more than common practice. I do this too, and it works very well. Cache busting is very important to ensure everyone is using the same version pushed, not only in css, but in other content too (hint:js). Also, to note, the browser *does* cache the resource with the `v` property, so there is no need to use `all.(v).css`. All that is needed is to change the value of v when you want to break the cache, it is a good approach to use.

Comment: @Thomas, I realize that you said it is working again, however I wanted to point out why your suggestion here is less than ideal. Notice how your suggestion changes the actual name of the file?  That means the filename in the HTML (or javascript) now has to be modified.  Although that can be done programatically, it is one more possible point of failure that then has to be tested.

Comment: @AndrewSteitz hm, but it seems the v parameter is added the same way, so I see no difference between the two, except my approach is more forgiving with "stupid" network policies in some places. I am used to this with the REST framework Sling where these parts before the extensions are called selectors.

Comment: @Thomas - the big difference has to do with cached HTML. If it references the old file, it will not exist using your scheme - in our scheme, worst case is one gets an old version (blocking like you experience not withstanding).

Comment: @Thomas, you are 100% correct that my comment made no difference whatsoever!  ;-)  Must have been tired when I posted it because I was thinking along the lines of Oded's explanation but obviously did not write it in a way that even came close.